# How to manually fire postback event to activate selectedIndexChanged event on the server side of a project Asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, postback, autopostback

Here is my problem, I have an mvc project with a `dropdownlist` control(Server Side) which i populate with data at run time, i have set `autopostback` to true,and enabled `viewstate`; this dropdown list has a `selectedIndexChanged` event handler which was suppose to trigger when a user selects something.

However when the page loads, the `Page.IsPostBack` is always false so the datalist is repopulated and hence no change to trigger the event handler. I have read on [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) post that while asp web forms take care of postback automatically, on MVC I have to manually write the javascript code to trigger the postback.

Do you guys know of any way i can do that so that it goes to the `selectedIndexChanged` EventHandler and dont repopulate the `dropdown list` again?

EDIT: I have already tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function OnIndexChanged() {
         var databaseList = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_DatabaseList");

         __doPostBack(FeaturedContent_DatabaseList, '');
         //window.location.href("http://localhost:49729/home/schemas?dbName=SchoolDB");//+ document.getElementById("DatabaseLists").selectedIndex;
         //postMessage("h", "http://localhost:49729/home/schemas?dbName=SchoolDB");
         //__doPost(
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you are using MVC. MVC doesn't use viewstate, or have an autopostback=true, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see, you are trying to use MVC. So forget the idea of postback, you will not reload the page every time. You will probably do ajax async request to the server. Here some code to get your event:

```
 $("#state").change(function(){
       //on-change code goes in here.
       //variable "this" references the state dropdown element
 });
```

its jQuery. *#state* is the id of your dropdownlist.

Comment: Why would i forget about postback

Comment: *MVC* is a designer pattern @fire'fly, There's tons of good books about it. I recommend u to read about it. Before trying to write code. Or just keep with *WebForms*. And yes, you don't have postback on *MVC* projects.